# How to get touch event on parent component area in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I used the following code on my react naive app.I disabled touch facility only on my child component.But I did not get touch event on area of child component.
How to resolve the issue?

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={[{ backgroundColor: 'red', padding: 10 }]}
    onPress={() => { this.showDatePicker() }}>
    <TextInput
        editable={false} selectTextOnFocus={false}
        style={textInput}
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple options

1.use store and create your application in mvvm pattern (
define a property as observable in your store and use it on your child component for disabling it and whenever you want to disable just change value on your store property)

2.pass as props to child component and define it

3. pass as props and use your chid like this

   {this.props.disabled && }

4.use ***ref*** in your parent component and get all child access

if you decide which of them is good for you i can explain more about it